# Browser forces me to download my index.jsp page instead of viewing it. I'm using github pages to host my project

Tags: eclipse, git, jsp, github, web-applications

I just finished making a webapp on Eclipse. I'm using a tom cat server. Anyways, I'm done with the project and want to upload it online on my GitHub repo. I made a branch for **gh-pages** and uploaded my **index.jsp** page. Unfortunately, when I navigate to the index.jsp link on my browser, it starts to download the file, instead of viewing the page.

Can someone please tell me how I can view the index page on my server instead  of it starting a download? I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub Pages [only host static content or Jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/):

> In addition to supporting regular HTML content, GitHub Pages supports [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) (which generates static content), a simple, blog-aware static site generator.

You can't run Java (or PHP, or Python, or .NET, or anything else) on them.

Comment: @ihoaxed, sorry, I'm not a Java guy so I don't have any real recommendations. I've used Heroku, AWS, and Digital Ocean for Python stuff and all of those should be able to handle Java too. But I'm not sure how far you'll be able to get for free. Good luck!